# Smowcode studio error 443 server not found

Tags: embedded, esp32, flow-based-programming

[image: Error Image]

I am not able to open Smowcode studio.
I tried to open Smowcode studio, and received an error at Smowcode server on port 443.
How to solve this error and open Smowcode studio?
Tried many ways but not able to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either of the following issues:

1. Another Smowcode Studio is open. (close it and try again)
2. Some other application in your computer is using the 443 port. (close it as
   well).